# How to get suggested addresses on some string entered by user using apple's Map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, google-places-api

I am new to iOS. I am using apple's Map. I need some functionality Like goole PlaceAutoComplete.

Before this I was trying to use PlaceAutoComplete By adding googlePlaces utility through pods, and function call back didn't even respond. I have created a iOS Api Key in regards with using googleMap placeAutoComplete utility.

Here is my piece of code

```
-(void)placeAutocomplete{
     GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
        filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity;
        [self.placesClients autocompleteQuery:self.txtFld.text
                                       bounds:nil
                                       filter:filter
                                     callback:^(NSArray *results,NSError*error)
        {
             if (error != nil) {
                 NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                 return;
             }
             self.autoCompleteArray = results;
         }];
    }
```

Comment: this is for google maps, not for apple maps. You need to have autocomplete for textfield.

Comment: Now I am using Google maps but same is the problem here, autocompleteQuery callBack doesn't being called.

Comment: Can you show some more code

Comment: I got it done using MVAutoCompleteTextField sdk. Thanks for your suggestion Mr.T :-)

Comment: Thanks for showing your enthusiasm for help @TheMall.

Comment: You welcome @SulmanMalik Have look at below answer as I did it just week ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it done either using search bar or making textfield's event textDidChange

I had that done using below code

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(requestForGoogleAutoCompletWithTask) object:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(requestForGoogleAutoCompletWithTask) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

}
-(void)requestForGoogleAutoCompletWithTask
{
    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc]init];
    [filter setType:kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter];

    GMSPlacesClient *placesClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];
    [placesClient autocompleteQuery:sBar.text
                             bounds:nil
                             filter:filter
                           callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                               if (error != nil) {
                                   NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                   arrAutoCompletData = results; // This is my actual array which I am showing in UITableView
                                   [tblView reloadData];
                                   return;
                               }
                               arrAutoCompletData = results;
                               [tblView reloadData];
                               for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Result '%@' with placeID %@", result.attributedFullText.string, result.placeID);
                               }
                           }];

}
```

Comment: But as I was trying this very same in shouldChangeCharachterInRange with UITextField, I came to know that  'callback:^' inner code never executed on my side (checked through debug points), even waited for 2-3 minutes as somewhere I read that it takes time to execute callBack.

Comment: Please notify this that I am using UIMapKit(Apple map).

Comment: May I know why you are using shouldChangeCharachterInRange with UITextField? and yes you have to put breakpoints inside the block to check whether code is executing or not. Like on this line you can put breakpoint `if (error!=nil)`. remove all break points and put that between `[placesClient autocompleteQuery:sBar.text
                             bounds:nil
                             filter:filter
                           callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error){......debug breakpoints for block must be between block...... }];`

Comment: ShouldChangeCharacterInRange is used because of the reason that I want to get the updated set of recommend Places  after each character change in the TextField.

Comment: Yes, as that of break points you said, I did exactly same steps to debug and check.

Comment: Hey @SulmanMalik you can get same functionality (i.e. I want to get the updated set of recommend Places after each character change in the TextField) by creating UITextField's `IBAction` named Editing Changed so it's advisable to use that one.

Comment: Yeah, ok I will try to attempt that next time. I have attained a lot some knowledge with your help 'TheMall' and I am very thankful to you for That. May GOD bless you. And I do expect the same kind of response further. Thanks Again.

Comment: That's Good Mr.Mall. Great Actually